# show image on overlay bug

Tags: html, image

I am a beginner in html. I have an image that has to be displayed on the overlay,when a button is pressed. Th problem is the image doesnot appear on the overlay for the first time. It appers only from the second time and then it works properly. If I refresh my page and do it again the image does not appear. The removing part has no error. So i did not include that part of the code.

```
var overlay = $(".ui-widget-overlay");
        baseBackground = overlay.css("background");
        baseOpacity = overlay.css("opacity");
        overlay.css("background", "#000").css("opacity", "1");
          function ShowOverlay() {
            $("<div id='overlay'> <img src='Images/ajax.gif'/>   </div>").appendTo('body');
                  $('#overlay').show();
```

Is it possible to add the image below _overlay.css("background", "#000").css("opacity", "1"); _  ?

Comment: try set `z-index` of image lower than overlay

Comment: you need to provide more that this to help you out .. atleast the click function ? A full working Fiddle would be great. Not just a code shot.

Comment: `function selectall()
  { 
   ShowOverlay();
   var msg = 'M';
   ws.send(msg); 
  }; `        This function selects all

Comment: `#overlay img {
    position:relative;    
    left:50%; 
    top:40%;
    z-index:100;    
}
`  I have the `z-index` in Modal.css

Comment: I would like to know is it possible to add the image in `var overlay function` ?

Comment: Thanks all, the problem was with the clash in the name of the image!